# Is there a way to disable last and first positions of a MUI Slider?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

By default MUI Slider thumb is going out of bounds of the track by the radius of the thumb in the first and last positions.

Let's see some examples on the screenshot below:

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDO5L.png)

code behind it:

```js
<Slider style={{ width: "400px" }} min={0} max={3} step={1} />
<Slider style={{ width: "400px" }} min={0} max={3} step={1} />
<Slider style={{ width: "400px" }} min={0} max={3} step={1} />
```

1. slider is in the first position
2. slider is in the midst position
3. slider is in the last position

Here's how I want it to be:

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObalS.png)

How I currently achieve that behaviour?

code behind it:

```js
<Slider style={{ width: "400px" }} min={-0.081} max={3.085} step={1} />
<Slider style={{ width: "400px" }} min={-0.081} max={3.085} step={1} />
<Slider style={{ width: "400px" }} min={-0.081} max={3.085} step={1} />
```

The side-effect to that code is that if we try, we can push the thumb to the right-most or left-most position (so it will be the same as on the first screenshot with the problem).

I was wondering how can one disable/disallow first and last positions of a Slider?

Maybe there are other ways to achieve this with css or something else, I'm open to any options.